# Extending a black box python module

Tags: python, python-2.7, cython

I have a "blackbox" python module which I would like to extend. The module provides a class `class Foo` with no `__init__` function, and a helper function `FooMaker` which returns objects of type `Foo`. The usual strategy of extending modules:

```
class ExtendedFoo(blackbox.Foo):
    def __init__(self, x):
        super(ExtendedFoo, self).__init__(x)
```

would not work here, since, as mentioned above I need to rely on `blackbox.FooMaker` instead of `Foo`'s `__init__` function.

Any ideas on how to extend the module `blackbox`?

Comment: Call FooMaker inside your init?

Comment: Use composition rather than specialisation

Comment: Do you want your `__init__` to run before or after FooMaker does whatever init'ish stuff it does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the `Foo` class had a setter function, so what eventually worked for me was

```
class ExtendedFoo(blackbox.Foo):
    pass

def ExtendedFooMaker(*args):
    _efoo = ExtendedFoo()
    _efoo.set(FooMaker(*args).get())
    return _efoo
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the same as your solution but is a bit shorter:

```
from blackbox import Foo, FooMaker

class ExtendedFoo(Foo):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.set(FooMaker(*args, **kwargs).get())
```